# Adding a day datetime in spring boot

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-boot

I am adding datetime in my project but I noticed that it is getting the wrong date
Today is 2023-03-21 23:03  and the date entered in the database is 2023-03-22 01:44:05.073000 I want the date in Brazilian format dd/mm/yyyy

follow below how I am declaring and inserting the date

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@JsonProperty("datebuy")
private Date datebuy;

 p.setDatebuy(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Could it be that the date is coming wrong because it doesn't have Brazilian locate? Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

[SOLVED]

using LocalDateTime like @Ryuzaki L said follow below my code

```
@Column(nullable = true,updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@JsonProperty("datebuy")
private LocalDateTime datebuy;

p.setDatebuy(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo")));


    CartPurchaseMongo catmongo = new CartPurchaseMongo();            
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String agoraFormatado = keyp.getDatebuy().format(formatter);
```

Comment: try add `@DateTimeFormat`

Comment: Do I Add with Date type and @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) annotation?

Comment: I do it this way to save with in mongodb

  `CartPurchaseMongo catmongo = new CartPurchaseMongo();
            Locale localeBR = new Locale("pt", "BR");
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",localeBR);
            String formattedDate = formatter.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));`

Comment: I think the problem is not the format but the time to insert

Comment: use java-8 date time object https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html\